# My custom fish shell prompt keeps resetting every reboot

Tags: linux, prompt, fish

I switched to fish shell a month ago and I'm quite pleased with it. But recently, my custom prompt keeps resetting to the default prompt every time I turn on my PC.

When opening the terminal, I'm welcomed with this :

> Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
>   Type **help** for instructions on how to use fish
>   set_color: Expected an argument
>   set_color: Expected an argument
>   my_login@my_hostname **~**>

Yet, My **`.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish`** contains the **`Classic + Git` prompt** chosen from the `fish_config prompt` command :

```
function fish_prompt --description 'Write out the prompt'

    set -l last_status $status

    # Just calculate these once, to save a few cycles when displaying the prompt
    if not set -q __fish_prompt_hostname
        set -g __fish_prompt_hostname (hostname|cut -d . -f 1)
    end

    if not set -q __fish_prompt_normal
        set -g __fish_prompt_normal (set_color normal)
    end

    if not set -q -g __fish_classic_git_functions_defined
        set -g __fish_classic_git_functions_defined

        function __fish_repaint_user --on-variable fish_color_user --description "Event handler, repaint when fish_color_user changes"
            if status --is-interactive
                set -e __fish_prompt_user
                commandline -f repaint ^/dev/null
            end
        end

        function __fish_repaint_host --on-variable fish_color_host --description "Event handler, repaint when fish_color_host changes"
            if status --is-interactive
                set -e __fish_prompt_host
                commandline -f repaint ^/dev/null
            end
        end

        function __fish_repaint_status --on-variable fish_color_status --description "Event handler; repaint when fish_color_status changes"
            if status --is-interactive
                set -e __fish_prompt_status
                commandline -f repaint ^/dev/null
            end
        end
    end

    set -l delim '>'

    switch $USER

    case root

        if not set -q __fish_prompt_cwd
            if set -q fish_color_cwd_root
                set -g __fish_prompt_cwd (set_color $fish_color_cwd_root)
            else
                set -g __fish_prompt_cwd (set_color $fish_color_cwd)
            end
        end

    case '*'

        if not set -q __fish_prompt_cwd
            set -g __fish_prompt_cwd (set_color $fish_color_cwd)
        end

    end

    set -l prompt_status
    if test $last_status -ne 0
        if not set -q __fish_prompt_status
            set -g __fish_prompt_status (set_color $fish_color_status)
        end
        set prompt_status "$__fish_prompt_status [$last_status]$__fish_prompt_normal"
    end

    if not set -q __fish_prompt_user
        set -g __fish_prompt_user (set_color $fish_color_user)
    end
    if not set -q __fish_prompt_host
        set -g __fish_prompt_host (set_color $fish_color_host)
    end

    echo -n -s "$__fish_prompt_user" "$USER" "$__fish_prompt_normal" @ "$__fish_prompt_host" "$__fish_prompt_hostname" "$__fish_prompt_normal" ' ' "$__fish_prompt_cwd" (prompt_pwd) (__fish_git_prompt) "$__fish_prompt_normal" "$prompt_status" "$delim" ' '
end
```

I've searched and found [this thread](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1335) but my problem seems a little bit different, and no clear solution was given.

I'm working with Manjaro (KDE desktop edition) 0.8.9, Terminator 0.97 and fish 2.1.0.

So, **has someone an idea as to why my prompt would reset like this** ?

Thank you.